# Is there a way to switch columns in paracol without introducing a paragraph break in the pre-switch column?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, paragraphs, paracol

(M)WE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\switchtoleft}{\switchcolumn[0]}
    \newcommand{\switchtoright}{\switchcolumn[1]*}

    \begin{paracol}{2}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi quis nisl dolor. Proin lobortis odio dolor, interdum volutpat nibh mattis a. Nam nec nulla in sapien sodales dictum. Etiam id ligula eu ligula tincidunt rutrum. Donec iaculis maximus felis, ut ullamcorper tellus vulputate et. Nulla fermentum, arcu non blandit efficitur, lectus turpis dapibus nunc, quis elementum turpis erat lacinia enim. Sed elementum massa vitae ligula posuere porta. Suspendisse ullamcorper dui ut erat luctus placerat. Pellentesque eu consequat nibh. Aenean rhoncus orci ex, consectetur faucibus lectus hendrerit nec. Donec tortor orci, eleifend vel vulputate in, fermentum eu elit.
        \switchtoright Pellentesque tempor risus tincidunt, vehicula nulla at, venenatis purus. Aliquam ante nisi, ornare scelerisque lorem semper, rhoncus sollicitudin diam. Etiam bibendum lacinia sem sed lacinia. Suspendisse ultrices pellentesque felis sed tincidunt. Vestibulum massa neque, fringilla eu nunc nec, accumsan tristique eros. Nunc et pulvinar odio. Morbi eu faucibus mauris. Praesent quis iaculis lectus, non efficitur risus. Pellentesque rutrum velit pretium nisi convallis, at vulputate nisl sodales. Curabitur at enim sollicitudin, gravida orci sed, vulputate sapien. Sed quam urna, tincidunt eu nibh at, feugiat pharetra lectus. Suspendisse vel iaculis eros. Vivamus dictum dolor a lectus commodo pharetra. Pellentesque vitae augue rhoncus, interdum dui id, placerat metus. Vestibulum sit amet ante vel justo imperdiet luctus.
        \switchtoleft Pellentesque congue sapien nisi, at euismod nisi ultrices vel. Vestibulum vestibulum eros magna, et suscipit orci dapibus at. Aenean eu urna ante. Quisque condimentum dui quis congue ultricies. Praesent ut laoreet eros, vel lacinia tellus. Nulla est turpis, vestibulum nec malesuada ut, imperdiet sollicitudin metus. Morbi lacinia felis vel justo laoreet vulputate. Duis condimentum mauris in dolor tincidunt, sed lobortis elit finibus. Aenean faucibus posuere efficitur. Phasellus sed odio et lacus condimentum accumsan eget congue dolor. Etiam condimentum felis lacus, a maximus neque porttitor vitae. Nullam sed risus ex. Nunc finibus eros at neque malesuada sodales. Suspendisse lacus neque, cursus id tempor sed, gravida non justo. Nunc tempor, massa non blandit semper, nunc dui tempus est, non mattis felis justo sit amet risus.
    \end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following:

[image]

I would like the text of the right column to begin at the same vertical position as `elit.` (just where it is now), but without adding a paragraph break between `elit.` and `Pellentesque` (in the left column). How would I do that?

Comment: Are there any constraints here? What does the actual text look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can fake it using `\tikzmark`, but you have to put the `\switchcolumn` at the end of the paragraph.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcommand{\switchtoleft}{\switchcolumn[0]}
\newcommand{\switchtoright}[1]% #1 = tikzmark name
{\switchcolumn[1]%
  \iftikzmark{#1}{\bgroup% synchronize pages
    \edef\markid{\csname save@pt@#1\endcsname}%
    \edef\markpage{\csname save@pg@\markid\endcsname}%
    \loop\ifnum\value{page}<\markpage\relax
      \null\newpage\repeat%
    \egroup}{}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,baseline=(here)]
  \coordinate(here) at (0,0);
  \coordinate(there) at (pic cs:#1);
  \path (here|-there);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{-.6\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi quis nisl dolor. Proin lobortis odio dolor, interdum volutpat nibh mattis a. Nam nec nulla in sapien sodales dictum. Etiam id ligula eu ligula tincidunt rutrum. Donec iaculis maximus felis, ut ullamcorper tellus vulputate et. Nulla fermentum, arcu non blandit efficitur, lectus turpis dapibus nunc, quis elementum turpis erat lacinia enim. Sed elementum massa vitae ligula posuere porta. Suspendisse ullamcorper dui ut erat luctus placerat. Pellentesque eu consequat nibh. Aenean rhoncus orci ex, consectetur faucibus lectus hendrerit nec. Donec tortor orci, eleifend vel vulputate in, fermentum eu elit.
\pgfmark{syncA}% \tikzmark alwo works, but \pgfmark works better
Pellentesque congue sapien nisi, at euismod nisi ultrices vel. Vestibulum vestibulum eros magna, et suscipit orci dapibus at. Aenean eu urna ante. Quisque condimentum dui quis congue ultricies. Praesent ut laoreet eros, vel lacinia tellus. Nulla est turpis, vestibulum nec malesuada ut, imperdiet sollicitudin metus. Morbi lacinia felis vel justo laoreet vulputate. Duis condimentum mauris in dolor tincidunt, sed lobortis elit finibus. Aenean faucibus posuere efficitur. Phasellus sed odio et lacus condimentum accumsan eget congue dolor. Etiam condimentum felis lacus, a maximus neque porttitor vitae. Nullam sed risus ex. Nunc finibus eros at neque malesuada sodales. Suspendisse lacus neque, cursus id tempor sed, gravida non justo. Nunc tempor, massa non blandit semper, nunc dui tempus est, non mattis felis justo sit amet risus.
\switchtoright{syncA}%
Pellentesque congue sapien nisi, at euismod nisi ultrices vel. Vestibulum vestibulum eros magna, et suscipit orci dapibus at. Aenean eu urna ante. Quisque condimentum dui quis congue ultricies. Praesent ut laoreet eros, vel lacinia tellus. Nulla est turpis, vestibulum nec malesuada ut, imperdiet sollicitudin metus. Morbi lacinia felis vel justo laoreet vulputate. Duis condimentum mauris in dolor tincidunt, sed lobortis elit finibus. Aenean faucibus posuere efficitur. Phasellus sed odio et lacus condimentum accumsan eget congue dolor. Etiam condimentum felis lacus, a maximus neque porttitor vitae. Nullam sed risus ex. Nunc finibus eros at neque malesuada sodales. Suspendisse lacus neque, cursus id tempor sed, gravida non justo. Nunc tempor, massa non blandit semper, nunc dui tempus est, non mattis felis justo sit amet risus.
\switchtoleft
    \end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image: synchronized paracol]